# PostgreSQL: LEFT JOIN does not return entire left table

Tags: sql, postgresql, left-join

I have 2 tables:

1. `town` which stores 290 towns
2. `hospital` which stores hospitals referenced in 67 different towns

The following query returns 290 rows which is what the LEFT JOIN is supposed to do:

```
SELECT a.code, count(b.*) 
FROM town a 
   LEFT JOIN hospital b ON a.code = b.town_code 
GROUP BY a.code ;
```

Now, the following query in which I just add a WHERE clause to select a type of hospital returns 56 rows:

```
SELECT
  a.code,
  count(b.*)
FROM town a 
  LEFT JOIN hospital b ON a.code = b.town_code
WHERE b.type = '01'
GROUP BY a.code ;
```

I don't understand why and I'm wondering how could I get my 290 rows issued with the second query as well?

Comment: The `where` clause on the outer table effectively turns the outer join into an inner join

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When `LEFT JOIN`, put the right side table's conditions in the `ON` clause to get true `LEFT JOIN` behavior. (When in the `WHERE` clause, you get regular `INNER JOIN` result.)

```
SELECT
  a.code,
  count(b.*)
FROM town a 
  LEFT JOIN hospital b ON a.code = b.town_code AND b.type = '01'
GROUP BY a.code
```

Comment: Thanks @jarlh! I didn't know that `AND` could be used within a `FROM`... Is the doc mentionning it somewhere?

Comment: The `AND` is a part of the `ON` clause here.

Comment: OK, didn't get that... Gooj job! Manys thanks again.